# Have I to credit imported bsd module in my python app?

Tags: bsd, python

I'm importrting colorama module licensed under BSD-3 licence to my python app. Have I to credit that module and how to do that on github?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The BSD-3 license requires that you:

1. Include the original copyright
2. Include the full text of the license in source or object code copies

Therefore, the only requirements when including a BSD-3 Licensed module in your app, is that you do not remove any copyright notices added by the module, or included within the modules source, and that you include a copy of the fulltext of the BSD-3 License with your project (indicating what code it pertains to, preferably).

The BSD-3 License does not require attribution, and so you are not *required* to include any attribution.

---

### Sources:

- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSD_licenses#3-clause_license_(%22BSD_License_2.0%22,_%22Revised_BSD_License%22,_%22New_BSD_License%22,_or_%22Modified_BSD_License%22))
- [OpenSource.org](https://opensource.org/licenses/BSD-3-Clause)
- [TLDRLegal](https://tldrlegal.com/license/bsd-3-clause-license-(revised)#fulltext)

Comment: OK thanks but if I only use 'import colorama' in my code and in my repo I don't store the source code of colorama module do I have to add the fulltext of the BSD-3 License?

Comment: You don't need to include anything then, since you're not including any source or object code copies.